# PHP - Cannot write in a file

Tags: php, fwrite

I want to write in a file with php but nothing seems to work :(

I tried everything i've sawn on internet :

this:

```
$file = fopen('text.txt', 'a+');
fputs($file, "a text");
fclose($monfichier);
```

and this :

```
$file = fopen('text.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($file, "a text");
fclose($monfichier);
```

and this :

```
file_put_contents("text.txt", "a text");
```

i also tried to put a sleep(1); before the fclose but it didn't change anything

my file and directory got 777 permissions, there is no error message, the functions don't return any error but the file is always empty u_u.

Can someone help please ?

Comment: Add the file path directory to your open_basedir, in php.ini, and restart php daemon

Comment: the file is already created *-*

Comment: You need to pass the variable`$file` in `fwrite` not the string `file`

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to access the right file? Use an absolute path perhaps...!?

Comment: Are you sure error reporting is on?

Comment: turn on error reporting, make sure you have the permissions and if selinux is enabled make sure the contexts are correct.

Comment: Are you going to respond to the multiple questions regarding error reporting...? That's the first thing to check here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most relevant and not erroneous code you show.
(all your code before have some invalid syntax)

```
file_put_contents("text.txt", "a text");
```

But this must normally work,
if this doesn't work too, i suggest you to looking for 
allowed path to write works.

You can edit for add it in you php configuration file (php.ini)
Find where are located you php.ini

from windows console

```
php --ini
```

or by echoing it with php builtin function

```
php_ini_loaded_file();
```

Verifying in your php.ini ([openbase_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) Doc's page)
and ad the full path when you want php are allowed the correct rights to manipulate files.

```
open_basedir = C:\you_path
```

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

And please check you error log, may be the solution is simply into you logs :)
Then in php.ini, again, check if this line is correctly filled

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

And do not forgot to restart your bundle httpd + php daemon before testing !

Comment: So i talked with my boss and changing the php.ini is more difficult than it looks like because our site has a strange think i don't really understood what but we could check our open_basedir and it was empty so i think the error comes from there

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the file name in fwrite() method.Try like this.Its working..

```
$file = fopen('text.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($file, "a text");
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputs.php)

> fputs — Alias of fwrite()

Then:

> int fwrite ( resource $handle , string $string [, int $length ] )

Try using

`fputs($file, "a text");`

Answer (score 0):

Your code 
`fclose($monfichier);` will give you the following error:

> PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

The following code will do the work:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('text.txt', 'a+');
fputs($file, "a text");
fclose($file);

?>
```